# Using .Net's StatisticFormula Library

Tags: c#, .net, normal-distribution

The C# namespace System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula seems to have a few statistical functions that I need.  The namespace is documented at [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula.aspx).  I'd really like to use the InverseNormalDistribution(double Z) function.  The problem is that the constructor is internal and so I can't access the functions in anyway that I know.

Is there some way to have access to the statics functions in this namespace, or will I have to find other solution?

Comment: can you show an example of what you have thus far in regards to C# code..? I think that it will make more sense once we can see what it is you are using and or how you are trying to implement the method

Comment: I was trying this: var stat = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula();
Console.WriteLine(stat.InverseNormalDistribution(0.5));  //It would give me a compiler error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably use reflection, something like this should do it:

```
var statisticFormula = 
    (StatisticFormula) typeof(StatisticFormula).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, Type.EmptyTypes, null).Invoke(null);
```

But this may be a better way:

```
var chart = new Chart();
var value = chart.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseNormalDistribution(.15)
```

Comment: That's just what I needed (The second part).  Thanks.

Comment: may want to add a using to the Chart, i.e. using (var chart = new Chart()) { return chart.DataM.....; }.  Funny how such usefull, reusable code is hidden away in such a cumbersome namespace and API.

Comment: Reflection doesn't work as there doesn't appear to be a non-public constructor for `StatisticFormula`. Even if there were, I doubt it would work because my effort to get to it with `StatisticFormula F = new DataManipulator().Statistics;` failed with a NULL pointer exception on the first call to one of the statistics methods.