# How to properly use DataFormula

Tags: c#, mschart

I am trying to use a DataFormula object in order to invoke some methods from the StatisticsFormula object exposed by it through the "Statistics" property.

I am able to instantiate the DataFormula object but when I try to call the InverseFDistribution method for instance, a NullReferenceException is thrown.

Could anyone clarify why this is happening? Am I using this class in a wrong way?

Best regards

Comment: You use the DataFormula methods as methods of the Chart's DataManipulator property: `var value = chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.InverseFDistribution(0.5d, 1, 1);` Or you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459066/using-nets-statisticformula-library)

Comment: is there a tag missing on this post?

Comment: @TaW, so I need to use a Chart object in order to use the DataFormula right? I though I could avoid the Chart class since I am only interested in the numerical result not creating any charts. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ja72 which tag would you suggest?

Comment: [tag:mschart] would do